# TSP on a subset of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization

**TL;DR: I have to use TSP on a subgraph of size $|V| = n$. I have to construct this subgraph out of a bigger graph. I have to find the subgraph that results in the shortest TSP solution. How to go about this?**

Graph $G(V, E)$ is a fully connected mesh in which each node is connected to all other nodes. The edges are of positive non-zero weights. Assume any two nodes $s, t \epsilon V$. The edge from $s$ to $t$ has a different weight than the edge from $t$ to $s$.

Now, for a given $n$, I have to find she shortest simple path that visits at least $n <= |V|$ nodes. This path needs to start and end in a given node $x \epsilon V$. As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527815/how-to-fix-the-start-and-end-points-in-travelling-salesmen-problem) post, I could add a dummy node that is bidirectionally connected to only node $x$ with edge weight 0. This would allow me to use a TSP solver in the special case where $n == |V|$. I read [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-solve-the-traveling-salesman-problem-a-comparative-analysis-39056a916c9f) that the 2-opt method is a suggested method if a good-enough result is appropriate (and it is for me).

However, in the case that $n < |V|$ I have the additional problem that I have to choose the nodes to be visited myself. More specifically, I have to choose the group of nodes that has the shortest TSP solution.

My question to you is, how would you handle the $n < |V|$ case? Maybe TSP is the wrong way to go about it alltogether. To me, the problem I'm facing sounds like a very standard problem in graph theory, but I have so far been unable to find a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of the *prize-collecting TSP problem* or *optimal subtour problem*.  A common approach is to introduce binary node variables and dynamically generate *generalized subtour elimination constraints (GSECs)* only when they are violated.

For a small enough graph, an alternative to dynamic constraint generation is to use the Miller-Tucker-Zemlin formulation.

Comment: Thank you I will look into that :)